# Logarithmic inequality difficulty

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Good day everyone, 
I  would need some assistance in solving this logarithmic inequality: 
$$\ln \frac {x - 1}{x + 1} \lt 1$$

The answer I came up with is:
$\frac {e + 1}{1 - e} \lt x \lt -1 \lor x \gt 1$.
Could you please give me a hand? Thank you very much.

Comment: You say that you have already come up with an answer. What exactly do you need a hand with???

Comment: The answer I came up with is not correct. So I needed a hand in finding the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

The domain is $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$.

the inequation is equivalent to
$$\frac{x-1}{x+1}<e$$

- in$(-\infty,-1)$, it becomes
  $x-1>e(x+1) \iff x<\frac{e+1}{1-e}\approx -2.1.$
- in $(1,+\infty)$, it becomes
  $x-1<e(x+1) \iff x>\frac{e+1}{1-e}$.

thus the solution is

$$(-\infty,\frac{1+e}{1-e})\cup(1,+\infty)$$

Comment: "the inequation is equivalent to..." You need $0$ on the left of that inequality.

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $0<(x-1)/(x+1) < e.$ I see now that you took care of this in your first line.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why did you have x < (e + 1)/(e -1) v x > 1 as solution. Please explain and thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. I get it now @SalahFatima. Thanks.

Comment: @SamuelJames Thanks too. you made me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First of all, we need $(x+1)(x-1)>0\implies$ either $x>1$ or $x<-1$

$\implies\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}<e$

If $x+1>0, x-1<e(x+1)\iff x>?$

If $x+1<0, x-1>e(x+1)<\iff x<?$

Comment: this is the right method but it is not working with my problem. See here: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201633/how-to-solve-this-logarithmic-inequality-with-another-logarithm-as-its-base][1]